How do I set up sequential numbering for a table in one field for each identical value in another field?
I have one table that gets a number of records imported into it several times a month. There are two fields I am trying to establish query programming for that will likely have to reference some VBA. I am a bit of an Access noob who sometimes has a hard time grasping how to cobble things together.
For each record in this table, the “SamplePeriod” column will already be populated with a value for each record that is imported. For each record with an identical value in this SamplePeriod field, I want a sequential three digit count (001) to populate the “Case#” column of the same table. Whenever new cases with a matching SamplePeriod value are added, I want the count to continue where it left off for that specific SamplePeriod value.
What would the VBA look like for this and then how would I call on this VBA to apply to all records within my table where the Case# field is blank (as those would be the newly imported records that need their SamplePeriod field looked at to generate the next sequential # in the Case#). The sequential numbering doesn’t have to reference any other data in each record to be in a certain order; I just want to assign a number to all the new cases but I do want a sequential order for each unique SamplePeriod value.
Thanks for any and all guidance!
I feel like DMAX will be involved, but I get overwhelmed with trying to make sense of the VBA. I learn so much from seeing how proven VBA code works but I have had a hard time finding the VBA relationship I am looking for.

Create a new case table with a SamplePeriod field and a 2nd field that is an auto-incrementing pk named Case#. Then Select distinct SamplePeriod from your importtable. Copy-paste the results into the case table. You now have a unique index for each Case#. Create a view that joins both tables on SamplePeriod  whenever you need the unique case# index.

If I understood your explanation correctly, you need to assign codes to new rows (records) after importing additional rows.
Take a look at the example.
There we take max current [Case#] for every SamplePeriod  - key value for this operation - thru DLookUp
nz(DLookUp("max([Case#])","YourTable","SamplePeriod =""" & SamplePeriod &""""),0)

Than increment this value as integer and cust to format '001'.
UPDATE YourTable 
SET YourTable.[Case#] 
    =right("000"  _ 
       & clng(nz(DLookUp("max([Case#])","YourTable","SamplePeriod =""" & SamplePeriod &""""),0))_ 
         +1 _
       ,3) 
where [Case#] is null or len([Case#])=0
;


Assuming you have an autonumber primary key or the equivalent, then Case# is just a calculated field and there is no need to put Case# into the table until the calculations become too burdensome to do on the fly.  In the same manner there is no need to format Case# until it is in the form or report.  I also abstract the calculation of Case# to a function for clarity and re-usability.
'Table1
-----------------------------------------------
|         ID         |      SamplePeriod      |
-----------------------------------------------
|                  2 | A                      |
-----------------------------------------------
|                  3 | A                      |
-----------------------------------------------
|                  4 | B                      |
-----------------------------------------------
|                  5 | B                      |
-----------------------------------------------
|                  6 | B                      |
-----------------------------------------------
|                  7 | C                      |
-----------------------------------------------

'Query1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|         ID         |      SamplePeriod      |     CaseNumber     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  2 | A                      | 1                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  3 | A                      | 2                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  4 | B                      | 1                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  5 | B                      | 2                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  6 | B                      | 3                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  7 | C                      | 1                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------


'put CalculateCaseNumber in a public code module
Public Function CalculateCaseNumber(sampleperiod As String, id As Long)
CalculateCaseNumber = DCount("ID", "Table1", "(ID < " & id & ") AND (SamplePeriod = '" & sampleperiod & "')") + 1
End Function

'since I chose to make sampleperiod a string and Dcount's parameters are strings, it may be hard to figure out the delimiters.  playing with the following debug.print in the immediate window may help.

debug.Print dcount("ID","Table1", "ID<3 AND SamplePeriod = 'A'")

edit: OP requested a way to insert CaseNumbers in original table only when CaseNumber is Null.  put the following sub routine into a public module then run it by highlighting and hitting run, or calling from a form, event, or immediate window.
'assuming Table1 has a CaseNumber column.
Public Sub InsertMissingCaseNumbersinTable1()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
If isnull(rs!casenumber) Then 'test for null
rs.Edit
Dim casenumber As Long
casenumber = DCount("ID", "Table1", "(ID < " & rs!id & ") AND (SamplePeriod = '" & rs!samplePeriod & "')") + 1 'remember this?
rs!casenumber = casenumber
rs.Update
End If
rs.MoveNext
Loop
'clean up
rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub


Wow, your solution and presentation was excellent!  Thank you for including both the VBA and examples on how to call it in a query.
I ended up adding the "CaseNumber" column to the Table1 and then creating an Update query with the following Update To field:  CalculateCaseNumber([SamplePeriod]),[ID])
it works great!  I have just a couple minor questions though…


As far as your VBA code goes, I was a little unsure about the debug addition, but I just added it to the bottom of the same public code module as your first bit of code, before the "End Function" portion. I am not really sure what that debug code does, but everything seems to work fine.



I would I inject some Criteria to only fill in blank or null CaseNumber fields?  For example, any time I am adding new records I wouldnt want to perform a recalculation of all of the CaseNumber fields for all records.  I tried sticking the following every combination of the following into the Criteria field of my Update query, but then the query kicked back a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" alert:

Is Null Or " " Or IsEmpty([SamplePeriod])

Can you help me figure out how to have the count and code executed but to only update/fill in blank CaseNumber field values?
thanks again!  You offered the best solution I have seen online for this.

Access has an immediate window(usually ctrl-g) that you can use to see and execute vba code.  debug.print can be run from the immediate window and debug.print outputs to the immediate window.

Thank you so much for the response! I am having a little trouble calling your new Public Sub in my Update query. Just to clarify, if I want only Nulls to be filled out, I should be replacing your initial function with the new code, right? I am only attempting to call your new code, just to clarify.  Is that right? . I added your new code to public module and created an Update query with the following "Update To" code: InsertMissingCaseNumbersinTable1([SamplePeriod],[ID]) but got "Undefined function 'InsertMissingCaseNumbersinTable1' in expression." Am I calling the new code incorrectly? thanks

Perhaps this explanation will help.  Missing data is a huge topic in both statistics and measurement.  In, short missing data is usually data.  The first and recommended approach treated your data as cleaned shaped and sacred.  A particular approach to handle the missing data was chosen for a set of analyses(reports).  The second approach assumes you are still cleaning the data and I gave you a routine that showed recoding false nulls as something else.  The two sets of code assume slightly different table structures.  One is run in a query, the other outside.  Both work adjust to your case
